# Type 'Color<ColorParam>' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-typescript

I am using `npm color` package. I am completly new to typescript react-native. Here I am trying to use Color property on `shadow color property` something like this.

```
const BACKGROUND = "#88B04B";
const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  topMorp: {
    shadowOffset: {
      width: -6,
      height: -6,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowRadius: 6,
    shadowColor: Color(BACKGROUND).lighten(0.5).alpha(0.5),
  },
```

But here my code complains saying `Type 'Color<ColorParam>' is not assignable to type 'string'`. I don't know how to fix this any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

```
//const BACKGROUND = "#88B04B";
const BACKGROUND = {r: 255, g: 255, b: 255}
......
{
    ...
    shadowColor: Color(BACKGROUND).lighten(0.5).alpha(0.5),
}
```

try to convert your color to rgb
i dont know how you implement Color (how to import)

Comment: "#88B04B" = rgb(135, 175, 75)

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe using `rgba` ?:

```js
const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  topMorp: {
    shadowOffset: {
      width: -6,
      height: -6,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowRadius: 6,
    shadowColor: 'rgba(135, 175, 75, 0.5)' //a is alpha
},
```

or use package maybe like:

```js
var color = Color('#88B04B').alpha(0.5).lighten(0.5);
const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  topMorp: {
    shadowOffset: {
      width: -6,
      height: -6,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 1,
    shadowRadius: 6,
    shadowColor: color     //Or maybe  color.hsl().string()
},
```